# Linkedin iOS login integration issue using SDK

Tags: ios, sdk, linkedin-api

The app opens ok and gives me login imput in an iPhone 6 but on an iPad 3 the login view wont apper, it just shows the normal linkedin starting page.

```
@IBAction func linkedinLogin(sender: AnyObject) {
    LISDKSessionManager.createSessionWithAuth([LISDK_FULL_PROFILE_PERMISSION], state: nil, showGoToAppStoreDialog: true, successBlock: { (returnState) -> Void in
        var session = LISDKSessionManager.sharedInstance().session
        println(" LinkedIn Login")
        var url = "https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~"
        if LISDKSessionManager.hasValidSession() {
            LISDKAPIHelper.sharedInstance().getRequest(url, success: { (response) -> Void in
                println("response: \(response.description)")
            }, error: { (error) -> Void in
                println(error)
            })
        }

    }) { (error) -> Void in
        println(error)
    }
}
```

Any ideas would be apreciated

Comment: I got the same problem, iPhone works fine but iPad stays on LinkedIn homepage. I asked LinkedIn on their developers forum but they send me here but got no answer yet.

Comment: @TomSpee if you get any answer from them I would love to hear it

Comment: Seems like the new linked in iPad app fixed the issues. If you still experience it try to re login your account.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing LISDK_FULL_PROFILE_PERMISSION with LISDK_BASIC_PROFILE_PERMISSION